# i want solve all this assessment in html and css

Tags: html

i need help to answer this technical assessement

Step 1
Within the STYLE tag, give the BODY element a white background
Create a BUTTON element with ID of filter-query, and give it a CSS class of `select-text`mdc-icon-button and material-icons. Set its text to filter_list.
Create a DIV element and give it a CSS class of select. Within the DIV, create a SELECT element with a CSS class of select-text
The SELECT element should have an option that is disabled and selected by defualt. Give this option any text you like, e.g "Select User"
Next, create a new DIV with a CSS class of user-photo. Inside it, create an IMAGE and set its src to a placeholder from https://placeholder.com/ Make sure to give your IMAGE an alternate text
Next, create a DIV with CSS class of details and mdc-elevation--z3. This DIV should have 5 PARAGRAPH elements, each containing a SPAN with CSS class prop and another SPAN with CSS class of value
Step 2
Using the SPAN elements so far created, your app will display the Age, Height, Weight, Gender, and Country of any given user. Let's call these the user properties!

For a given user property, e.g Age, locate a PARAGRAPH element and give the child SPAN with class prop an HTML attribute of data-age, then set its text value to Age :. The SPAN with class value should have an HTML attribute of data-age-value. The HTML attributes do not need to have a vlaue.
Just like for Age, do same for all the user properties listed above, such that all pairs of SPAN elements are mapped to excatly one user property. Feel free to order them anyhow you like.
Step 3
Create a BUTTON with an ID of oracle and CSS class of mdc-button. Give the button an call-to-action text of your choice, e.g "Calculate BMI"
Create a DIV an ID of outcome. Within it, create a HEADING element with CSS class of mdc-typography--headline5. Set the text of the HEADING to BMI.
Next to the HEADING and still within the DIV with ID of outcome, create an empty PARAGRAPH.
Time to make your app look good. To get a better preview as you go along, feel free to set some dummy data values in the SPAN elements for each user property

Step 4
The .select DIV should have a bottom margin of 2.5em
The .user-photo DIV wrapping the user's IMAGE should have 150px of width and height, and styled to display as a circle. You might need to explore the overflow CSS property to make the IMAGE comply with the circular shape of the DIV
Step 5
The .details DIV should have white foreground color and #6200ee background color, font size of 1.3em, top margin of 4em, padding top/bottom of 0.5em and padding left/right of 1em, and optional curved edges of 10px
The PARAGRAPH elements within the .details DIV should have margins of 0.3em
The DIV with ID of outcome should use absolute positioning, with 2.2em from the right edge and 6.5em from the bottom edge of the viewport. It should be 100px wide, and have centered text.
The HEADING within the DIV with ID of outcome should have 1em padding, white background, 10% curved edges, and no margins.
The PARAGRAPH within the DIV with ID of outcome should have a white foreground color, solid white 5px bottom border, 2em font size, no margins, 0.5em top/bottom padding and no left/right padding
Step 6
The BUTTON with ID of oracle should have 2.5em top margin, solid 1px border, and occupy the available horizontal space.

Comment: 1. What do you need help on? Do you need help on a specific question or all of them? 2. Please provide any code that you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" 
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <title>Mini App</title>

    <style>
      body{background:#ffffff}
      div.select{margin-bottom:2.5em}
      div.user-photo {
        margin: 1em auto;
        height:150px;
        width:150px;
        border-radius:50%;
        overflow:hidden;
      }
      div.details{color:#ffffff; 
      background:#6200ee; font-size:1.3em; 
        margin-top:4em; 
        padding:0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; 
        border-radius:10px;}
      .details p{margin:0.3em}
      div#outcome{position:absolute; 
        right:2.2em; 
        bottom:6.5em; 
        width:100px;
        text-align:center}
      #outcome h5{padding:1em; 
        background:#ffffff; 
        border-radius:10%; 
        margin:0 }
      #outcome p{height:40px; 
        color:#ffffff;
        border-bottom:5px solid #ffffff; 
        font-size:2em; 
        margin:0; 
        padding:0.5em 0 0.5em 0;}
       #oracle{margin-top:2.5em; 
        border: 1px solid; 
        width:100%}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <button id="filter-query" class="mdc-icon-button material-icons">filter_list</button>
    <div class="select">
      <select class="select-text"><option disabled selected>Select User</option> 
      </select>
       <div class="user-photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"  alt="user photo"/>
    </div>
    <div class="details mdc-elevation--z3">
      <p><span class="prop" data-age="">Age :</span><span class="value" data-age-value>35</span></p>
      <p><span class="prop" data-height="">Height :</span><span class="value" data-height-value>1.6m</span></p>
      <p><span class="prop" data-weight="">Weight :</span><span class="value" data-weight-value>75kg</span></p>
      <p><span class="prop" data-gender="">Gender :</span><span class="value" data-gender-value>Male</span></p>
      <p><span class="prop" data-country="">Country :</span><span class="value" data-country-value>Nigeria</span></p>
      </div>
    
      <button id="oracle" class="mdc-button">Calculate BMI</button>
      <div id="outcome"><h5 class="mdc-typography--headline5" >BMI</h5><p></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help Dear i really apreciate from the bottom of my heart.