# how do i create a DIV with 5 PARAGRAPH elements, each containing a SPAN with CSS class prop and another SPAN with CSS class of value

Tags: html

i want to create a DIV with CSS class of info and mdc-elevation--z3. This DIV should have 5 PARAGRAPH elements, each containing a SPAN with CSS class char and another SPAN with CSS class of worth

Comment: What have you tried? Didn't you ask this yesterday?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i want solve all this assessment in html and css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008620/i-want-solve-all-this-assessment-in-html-and-css)

Comment: @j08691 No, that was somebody else. The whole classroom is asking this on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Emmet:

`div.info.mdc-elevation--z3>p*5>span.char+span.worth`

Expanded:

```
<div class="info mdc-elevation--z3">
  <p><span class="char"></span><span class="worth"></span></p>
  <p><span class="char"></span><span class="worth"></span></p>
  <p><span class="char"></span><span class="worth"></span></p>
  <p><span class="char"></span><span class="worth"></span></p>
  <p><span class="char"></span><span class="worth"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
<div class="mdc-elevation--z3">
<p><span class="char"></span><span class="worth"></span></p>
<p><span class="char"></span><span class="worth"></span></p>
<p><span class="char"></span><span class="worth"></span></p>
<p><span class="char"></span><span class="worth"></span></p>
<p><span class="char"></span><span class="worth"></span></p>
</div>
```